# The probability of a diagnostic method gives the correct result of the state of a disease

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let us say we have a disease, and for each patient, the state of the disease is unobserved, and we model it with the binary random variable $X:\{\text{patients}\}\longrightarrow \{0,1\}$, where $X = 0$ when the patient is health, and $X = 1$ when the patient is infected.

We have a diagnostic method, but we don't know if it can absolutely give the correct result. So, we model it using another random variable (but it is observed), $Z:\{\text{patients}\}\longrightarrow \{0,1\}$, where $Z = 0$ when the diagnosis is negative and $Z = 1$ when the diagnosis is positive.

We don't know how to model $P(X=0)$ nor $P(Z=0)$, but we know the conditional probability $$P(Z = z|X = x),\ \text{where}\ z,x\in\{0,1\}.$$

For example, we can then know the probability of the diagnostic method missing the presence of the disease, where is: $$P(Z=0|X=1)$$

However, is there any way to get he probability of the diagnostic method gives the correct result from the condition probability? I am not sure if the following is correct: $$P(\text{the diagnostic method gives the correct result})=P(Z=0|X=0)+P(Z=1|X=1).$$ I don't think that it is correct, but I don't know what the correct alternative is.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, you also need to know the true probability that the patient has the disease.  Suppose, say, that the test is $99\%$ accurate for healthy people but only $70\%$ accurate for people with the disease.  Now imagine scenarios in which, say, $95\%$  of people are healthy or (alternatively) $95\%$ of the people have the disease.

Comment: @lulu I am sorry in this case how do we compute the desired probability? Use law of total probability?

Comment: What you want is $P(Z = X) = P(X = 0, Z = 0) + P(X = 1, Z= 1).$ For example, $P(X = 0, Z = 0) = P(Z = 0 \mid X = 0) P(X = 0),$ and similarly when $1$ replaces $0.$ So, you get $P(X = Z) = P(Z = 0 \mid X = 0)P(X =0) + P(Z = 1 \mid X = 1)P(X = 1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of conditional expectation $P(A \mid B) P(B) = P(A \cap B)$ (assuming $P(B)$ is positive). Note that the event you are interested in is $\{X = Z\}.$  Then
$$
P(X = Z) = \sum_{t = 0,1} P(Z = t \mid X = t) P(X = t).
$$